# How do I loosen the zOrder of an Eclipse RCP application detached windows, on MacOS?

Tags: java, macos, swt, eclipse-rcp

On MacOS, the detached views of an Eclipse RCP application have a fixed zOrder, based on creation time.  That is, if I detach View A and then detach View B, the latter will always be above the former, regardless which one is focused.

Eclipse itself has this behavior. It doesn't happen on Windows: the focused detached view stays above the others.

Trying to solve the problem, we found that:

- Creating a new Shell without a parent solves the zOrder issue, but the main windows hides the detached views when it is focused.
- Creating a new Shell with SWT.ON_TOP style solves the main-window-above-detached-views problem, but then the detached views stay above every other window open, even the ones from other programs.

We couldn't understand if there's something wrong with the creation of detached views on Eclipse or if there's a system setting on MacOS that could make them behave as they do on Windows.  We tried various style combinations while creating new Shells, with various different behaviors but none of them work as expected.

Hence, the question.  How do I loosen the zOrder of an Eclipse RCP application detached windows, on MacOS, in order to make them behave as they do on Windows?

Comment: I can't find anything that would change this in the SWT APIs. It looks like the macOS windows APIs can do it but SWT doesn't have anything to call the right APIs.

Comment: Precisely.  I have seen there are apps that can do that on MacOS, so surely there's a way.  I expect there's some tricky combination of settings I'm missing.

Comment: No. Just because the underlying macOS APIs can do it does not mean that the SWT APIs support it. SWT does not support everything that the underlying window APIs can do. I have spent several hours looking at this and I don't see anything.

Comment: Let me correct my previous comment:  I *expected* there was some tricky combination.  Oh, gosh.  Do you think this could be supported on a future release of SWT?

Comment: You would do better to ask about future support on the SWT Github discusssions - [here](https://github.com/eclipse-platform/eclipse.platform.swt/discussions)

Comment: For sure!  I've been there before.  Thanks for the help, Greg!

Comment: I might be totally wrong, but I am not aware of anything *inside* SWT to support zOrder. As to my (incomplete) experience, SWT lays out everything *flat*. By opening a new Shell, you create a window in the underlying graphic system, as akin to open a new application that shadows the current one. Nothing to do with SWT as such.